# PyQt5 and initializing/finalizing the python interpreter

Tags: python, c++, macros, pyqt5, finalization

I have an application that can be extended using Python macros. As python is not often used, for every macro, I initialize the python interpreter, run the macro, and then finalize the interpreter.

Everything works just fine, with the exception of PyQt5: after the end of the first macro, all classes disappear from the PyQt5 modules. I guess this is a problem with static variables and the PyObject being destroyed when finalizing. But is there something to do beside never killing the Python interpreter?

Here is the code of my macro:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

def initialize(X, Y, Z, printed, parent):
    X, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getDouble(parent, "Select radius", "X = ", float(X), 0, 10)
    if not ok:
        return False
    return X, X, X, printed
```

On first run, I have the dialog box, but on the any other run I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/macros/TestBlur.py", line 13, in initialize
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QInputDialog'
```

**Edit**: Maybe another way to see this is: is there a way to explicitely instantiate all the classes for PyQt5, in the same way you have to call `import_array` to initialize the `numpy` library?